# Jquery gets new value from dom

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my page I am trying to hold old value and when something gets wrong I need to get it back.

```
ex:

var $oldVal;

$(document).delegate('.edit','click',function(){

   $oldVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input'); 

});

$(document).delegate('.save','click',function(){
  $.get('servlet',function(result){
     if (result.result == "true"){
        $newVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input');
      }else if ( result.result == "false" ) {
        $newVal = $oldVal; // 
        }
   });
});
```

When I try to get new val in $.each like this;

```
    $.each($newVal,function(k,v){
       value = $(v).val(); ///  PROBLEM ( 1 ) 

    });
```

It will never get the old value. It always gets the new one. I am trying to make an input box that will be same after user input is right but if it is wrong then it needs to get older value.

Answer (score 0):

All you're saving is a jQuery wrapper around the DOM element. You're not making a copy of the value.

```
var oldVal;

$(document).on('click', '.edit', function(){

   oldVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val(); 

});
```

That way you save the actual *value* of the input, so that if it changes you can restore it.

Note that the `.delegate()` API has been obsolete for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are storing the input element, not the value of the input element. The value can change while the input element stays the same.

To store the *value*, you should do this:

```
oldVal = $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val();

//...

if (!result.result) {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('input').val(oldVal);
}
```